# Use more than one Content type hub in the same Web Application?

Tags: 2013, content-type-hub, sharepoint-on-prem

We have a scenario where this organization have multiple vendors. Each vendor (currently two) need a Content Type Hub. Our goal is to minimize administration and we’re thinking what we should do.

[image]

We can have one content type hub with one site collection in a stand-alone web application. Vendors need to deploy there content types to the same site collection with the risk of that they named their content types and site columns the same way. We do have development environment, acceptance test environment and production environment so no harm to the production environment would happen unseen. But we’re trying to figure out a way to isolate content type hubs from each other.

Our idea is to create a Content Type Web Application, have an empty root site collection in it and further down in the hierarchy use one site collection per required solution, like this:

[image]

Then we could isolate applications from each other but still make use of shared content types when needed. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to have them follow a standard naming convention for the Content Type names, like VendorName(or abbrev) Document, VendorName Project, etc and use separate groups. They could then use a singular CT hub and would reduce collisions. This gives total visibility to everyone and can help with governing it too. I would fear that if it was at the site collection level, you would have less visibility and would have an increased collision possibility.